# Installing an ubuntu 22.04 server on wifi and then connecting an ethernet adapter

Tags: networking, ubuntu, netplan

I am turning an old laptop into a server for reasons.
I installed ubuntu server edition on it, and at the time I did not have an ethernet adapter, just a wifi card on the laptop.
subiquity did it all just fine.
Now, equipped with an ethernet adapter, I want to use that connection.
I lshw-ed to find out that the interface was a priory disabled, so I re-enabled it.
then should I just dhclient mynterfacename to proceed?

If I turn off the laptop/server, it falls back to its previous configuration.
In my Wishlist :

- renaming my interface from myinterfacename (or whatever outlandish name ubuntu has chosen) to eth0
- configuring that before trying wifi, it tries eth0

I understand I should use netplan, since the answers to older configurations do not seem to apply, but I don't really know how to

- if there a way to run a subiquity type program after installation so that it sets it all without my looking?

Comment: ubuntu configures itself when installing but not once installed.. i had the same problem as you, the solution is to google a bunch of pages showing you how to setup a new internet conection using some yaml files and services